# iOS 6.1.3 delete update to iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm upgrading my mum's iPad from iOS 6.1.3 to 9.3 and it is coming up with a verification error. The obvious solution is to redownload the update and update from there.

There is however one issue, I can't find the update in Settings. All guides say to go to `Settings > General > Storage & iCloud usage > Manage storage`

however I just have:

`Settings > General > Usage`

and then a list of apps (none of which are iOS 9.3 or even add up the the total data usage) and below that settings for managing iCloud.

So my question is what is the procedure to delete the update on the ipad.

Comment: Your question has conflicting information. You say you're getting a verification error, but are trying to (I assume) free up space? Why not try upgrading the device using iTunes.  It also will probably be in your best interest to do a system restore while updating the device.

Comment: @Cjen1 Please leave a comment below my answer and tell me if it helps or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to do, but it sounds to me like you're trying to upgrade an iPad over-the-air. This should work, but transcending multiple operating system versions on your way up can cause problems. And could you be out of storage space?

Since this method isn't working, you should try [the other method](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204204) (scroll down after opening that link), which is updating the iPad via iTunes.

1. Plug the iPad into a Mac with iTunes installed.
2. Make the devices trust each other (accept trust if prompted)
3. Ensure the iPad is [backed up to either iCloud or iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977).
4. When the prompt is displayed on the Mac ("Would you like to update the software on this iPad") choose `Download and Install` to start the update.

Let the iPad update, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Yeah so this was what I ended up doing but on a windows PC, it went perfectly

Comment: @Cjen1 Great! Feel free to check off my answer if it was the one ;).

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't actually get your answer until afterwards but it is the correct answer